# Changing the scope of "let" declaration

Tags: typescript, declare, let, redeclaration

I want to run a script multiple time, and I don't know whether it's first run or not - so I have to ask, and if so, I'll declare it:

`if (typeof variable == undefined)  { let variable = new Set(); }`

Unfortunately
1.) re-declaring with `let variable;` all the time throws an error
2.) This variable is live only in the "if" scope
3.) Command "let" require a full block if, ternary or "braclet-less if" throws an error

Can I change the scope of the variable? Just like the good-old `var` - I have no problem with that, I just want to use Set (and also a good lecture to know whether it's possible or not)
Maybe some "declare if not declared" command?

Comment: It's quite strange for a single script to run code at the top level *twice*, and to also not know if it'd been run before. If you have to do it, assign to the global object instead of using `let` (or `var`)

Comment: I agree w/ @CertainPerformance - it's a bit of a code smell, but if necessary assigning to the global object would probably be preferable.  If for some reason _that_ is not possible or desirable, you could also just declare the `let` _outside_ of the `if` block and only assign in the `if` block.  Which, now that I type that, how are you interrogating the `typeof` of `variable` in the `if` condition before it has been declared?  That seems like it should be throwing an error...  I think you may have larger structural issues in your code.  You shouldn't need `var`; `let` should be sufficient.

Comment: How can I declare globally? It's ok for me. Sure, if I start script runnings with a single ```let variable;``` it will work fine. If that's what you wanted to say.
Also ```if typeof``` is working for me with any variables, try it yourself now in console. It's just a personal 10-row code, nothing big (gather links and memorize it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm, not sure what are you trying to do exactly.
Is the code run in the browser?

If so, you can try and omit var/let/const keywords:

```
if (typeof variable == undefined)  { variable = new Set(); }
```

This will create a variable in the window object if it doesn't exist

[EDIT]:
Of course, you can make it "better" by being explicit about the object where the global variable comes from.

for browsers this code would become:

```
if (typeof window.variable == undefined)  { window.variable = new Set(); }
```

If you are working in a team this solution is better, but if you're just starting out or trying to learn, both are fine.

Comment: This is close to what is recommended in the comments.  However, why not be specific, and just do `if( typeof window.variable === undefined) { window.variable = new Set(); }`?  Most linters won't like you using undeclared variables, nor is it acceptable in strict mode.  Also, it might be acceptable to shorten the condition itself and write it simply as `if (!window.variable) { window.variable = new Set(); }`

Comment: Yes! This is working! Wow, so that is what they mean about "global", nice! Thanks. I tought "let" is mandatory for these special TS types.
Using window is the same, sure, can be better at some point.

So, for the knowledge: can't you set the scope of the let? Like... eg. a function, where is an if, and you want the "let" inside the "if" to be in the "function" '-s scope!? (hm.. probably only with Alex's trick: using objects.....)

Comment: You cannot change the scope of let. I will always be the first braces `{}`. So if/function/for loop etc. will have a separate variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply declare variable first then do operations on it.

```
let variable; // declare variable 

if (typeof variable === 'undefined') { variable = new Set(); }
```

It should not throw any of the error you mentioned.

Comment: Ah... yes that will not throw an error, but it makes no sense since the variable will be redeclared, and will be undefined, so the if statement will be always true

Comment: @cncDAni3 this depends on your logic before if condition you might perform any other logic etc, but the best way is to always declare a variable with default value, I dont know what you wanna do but that is the standard way.